# CSV file upload and update table data into MySQL[Issue in Loop]

Tags: php, mysql, csv, prestashop-1.6

Trying to update(if changes in product price) and insert new product in product table by using code given below.

```
$connection = mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);
$dbs_select = mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_);

// read the csv file in the form of array
function readCSV($csvFile) {
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

//Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = '/home/demorct/public_html/prestashop/first import.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
// CSV PArsing
$flag = 0;
foreach ($csv AS $csvdata) {
   $flag = $flag + 1;
   if($flag ==1){
       continue;
   }
    $csvdata1 = $csvdata['0'];
    $dataparsing = explode(";", $csvdata1);
    $BrandName = $dataparsing[0];
    $Modele = $dataparsing[1];
    $Ome = $dataparsing[2];
    $Gamme = $dataparsing[3];
    $Article = $dataparsing[4];
    $Abregee = $dataparsing[5];
    $Designation = $dataparsing[6];
    $Contenance = $dataparsing[7];
    $Page = $dataparsing[8];
    $Color = $dataparsing[9];
    $Weight = $dataparsing[10];
    $Code = $dataparsing[11];
    $Packagingimage = $dataparsing[12];
    $Productimage = $dataparsing[13];
    $Famille = $dataparsing[21];
    $Finalprice = $dataparsing[24];
    $status = $dataparsing[25];
    $quantity = $dataparsing[26];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  

  echo $productselect = "select  * from `ps_product` where `price` <> '$Finalprice' or `reference` <> '$Article' or `ean13` <>  '$Code' or `is_referenceoem` <> '$Ome' or `Range` <> '$Gamme' or `PackagingImage` <> '$Packagingimage' or `DesignationResume` <> '$Designation' or `Containance` <>  '$Contenance' or `Capacity` <> '$Page' or `quantity` <> '$quantity' or `color` <> '$Color' or `modele` <> '$Modele'";
          $result =  mysql_query($productselect) or die(mysql_error());
          while($dataArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
              echo "<pre>";
           echo $test = $dataArray['id_product'];
                $existrate = $dataArray['price'];
                $reference = $dataArray['reference'];
                $ean13 = $dataArray['ean13'];
                $is_referenceoem = $dataArray['is_referenceoem'];
                $Range = $dataArray['Range'];
                $PackagingImage = $dataArray['PackagingImage']; 
                $Containance = $dataArray['Containance'];
                $DesignationResume = $dataArray['DesignationResume'];
                $Capacity = $dataArray['Capacity'];
                $quantity = $dataArray['quantity'];
                $color = $dataArray['color'];
                $modele = $dataArray['modele'];
             echo "</pre>";

//MANUFACTURE ID
    $select_10 = "select * from `ps_manufacturer`";
    $result_10 = mysql_query($select_10);
    while ($row10 = mysql_fetch_array($result_10)) {
        $id_manufacturer = $row10['id_manufacturer'];




               echo "<br/>Final = $Finalprice, Existing = $existrate <br />"; 


          if (( $existrate!= $Finalprice ) && ($reference!= $Article) &&  ( $ean13!=$Code ) &&  ($is_referenceoem!= $Ome )){



         $mysql = "INSERT IGNORE  INTO `ps_product` (`id_category_default` ,`id_manufacturer`,`reference`,`ean13`,`is_referenceoem`,`price`,`PackagingImage`,`DesignationResume`,`Containance`,`Capacity`,`Range`,`date_add`,`quantity`,`color`,`modele`) VALUES(1,$id_manufacturer,'$Article','$Code','$Ome','$Finalprice','$Packagingimage','$Designation','$Contenance','$Page','$Gamme','$date','$quantity','$Color','$Modele')    ";
        mysql_query($mysql) or die(mysql_error());

          } else { echo $rateUpadte = "UPDATE `ps_product` SET `price` = '$Finalprice' , `reference` = '$Article' ,`ean13` = '$Code' ,`is_referenceoem` = '$Ome' WHERE `id_product` = ".$value;
            mysql_query($rateUpadte) or die(mysql_error());


          } 
    }

          }
          $flag++;   
 }
```

Product price must take as per csv file

CSV file example:

Product id   Product price
1              10
2              50
3              28
4              48
5              69

Currently price update in product table in db table but somewhere loop does not work as expected. Code works but it print product price in multiple times and sometime it shows last price of last product or display 00 when query run.

Output example given below...

One time query run and insert data in table as...(in most cases)

Product id   Product price
1                00
2                00
3                00
4                00
5                00

One time query run and insert data in table as...(sometime)
Product id   Product price
1                69
2                69
3                69
4                69
5                69